# How to fetch forms data submitted in a wordpress plugin file?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I want to submit a form which contains a `textarea` to my Wordpress plugin. But I don't know exactly HOW. I want my plugin to fetch the $_POST variable after the submission of the form that I create for it. The other idea would an setting fields. Having setting fields to save some data in it then accessing them via plugin. All in all, I want to be able to access the setting form, `input`, `textarea` and other form elements values through my Wordpress plugin. I know the question sounds novice, I couldn't find any search result regarding my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function in your plugin and add it into the [init action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init). This is a great time to intercept `$_POST` data and do with it what you wish.

```
function intercept_post_data() {
    // do things with the $_POST array
}
add_action( 'init', 'intercept_post_data' );
```

However, you also have the option to `POST` directly to your plugin by changing the form's `action` to point to a plugin file that handles form processing. (I recommend the first option).

Comment: Where should my form action refer to in former case? Am I free to choose whatever field name I want to be assigned to POST after form submission? How should I create my form in the admin panel?

Comment: The form action can be anything in the former case. I'd probably end up completely omitting the action, so that it submits to the current page. I'm not sure if I understand the other questions.

Comment: So you mean the Wordpress has the intelligence to fetch the POST data to whatever page the action is defined to? Then give plugin the access to manipulate it?

Comment: Well that's the point of the action hook. The `init` action is run every time a page is loaded (and is run after plugins are loaded). This means that as long as your plugin is loaded, any function that has been hooked into `init` will run when the page is loaded.

Comment: I would appreciate your help if you could give an example of form submission in Wordpress. Like creating a setting page then submitting some info.

Comment: That's a huge question with a huge answer (way too long for this format on Stack Overflow). You need to read up on WordPress plugin development and the HTTP request/response cycle.

Comment: Could you please give me some robust resources to start from? I am not aware of the google keywords to get the intended result.